# Is there a difference between USB 1.0 symbol and USB 2.0 symbol?

Tags: usb

Is there a difference between USB 1.0 symbol and USB 2.0 symbol?

I know USB 3 has a symbol distinct as it has 'ss'  <s>and USB 3.0 has a slight distinction in symbol from USB 3.1..</s> And I know that modern laptops are all just USB 3.

But I am wondering the difference in symbol between 1.0 and 2.0?

Comment: *USB 3.0* is also known as *USB 3.1 Gen 1*. USB 2 is High-Speed

Comment: AT Ramhound, you write "USB 3.0 is also known as USB 3.1 Gen 1" <-- That doesn't agree with this from wikipedia  "USB 3.1, released in July 2013, is the successor standard that replaces the USB 3.0 standard. USB 3.1 preserves the existing SuperSpeed transfer rate, giving it the new label USB 3.1 Gen 1, while defining a new SuperSpeed+ transfer mode, called USB 3.1 Gen 2 which can transfer data at up to 10 Gbit/s over the existing"

Comment: I indicated that USB 3.0, USB 3.1 Gen 1, and USB 3.2 Gen 1 are all the same standard.  I left out USB 3.2 Gen 1 from my original statement, but your quote, says exactly what I said.  Modern laptops are certainly not all USB 3.  USB 2 is HighSpeed while USB 3 is SuperSpeed, USB 3.1 Gen 2 and USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 have their own speed identity

Comment: AT Ramhound. I see what you mean, You're better than wikipedia there as wikipedia didn't really clearly mention that  point you essentially make that I see is the case, about USB 3.0 being renamed to USB 3.1 Gen 1.

Comment: You are aware that quote, from Wikipedia, specifically stated that fact?  I already knew that USB 3.0 was (USB 3.1 Gen 1 or USB 3.2 Gen 2).

Comment: AT Ramhound  I don't know how clear that particular wikipedia quote was, for example I guess a standard has/defines a rate,  A standard might be a rate plus other information. . "preserves the existing SuperSpeed transfer rate"    might not preserve the contents of the existing standard. For example there may be some words or terms in the 3.0 standard that aren't in the 3.1 standard. So it may be that the 3.0 standard is not fully contained within the 3.1 standard.

Comment: Your statement "USB 3.0 is also known as USB 3.1 Gen 1"  implies that the USB 3.0 standard is fully contained in 3.1 i.e. that USB 3.1 Gen 1 standard has all the words no more and no less as USB 3.0 standard

Comment: And even if we put aside the question of whether the standard, USB 3.0 and USB 3.1 Gen 1, have some word differences(which wikipedia isn't explicit about). I'd guess it may well do.(in which case it's not a case of the latter being a new name for the former). But besides that.    It may be that the implementation of each, is the same not just in speed, or it may be that the implementation shares speed, but differs slightly in other regards.

Comment: If indeed the implementation is the same not just in speed, then wikipedia would be more clear if it said that it preserves the existing implementation[i.e. speed plus whatever else re implementation], rather than just preserves the existing speed.

Comment: Also there's a difference between "replaced" and "renamed". It may be that the USB 3.0 standard is replaced with a different one, USB 3.1 Gen 1,that maintains completely the implementation.  So the standard is replaced  but an/any implementation is maintained, the same / fits as an implementation of the new standard. That doesn't mean that the old standard exists [suggestion of perhaps to the letter], under a different name.

Comment: Also, if you replace something, the replaced thing perhaps doesn't really exist anymore. If you rename something, it does still exist completely, in every way, but just under a different name.. So replace and rename aren't quite equivalent terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between the USB 1.0 and 2.0 symbol, but there is a difference between the USB 2.0 and 3.0 symbol, shown by the SS on the USB 3.0/3.1 Gen 1 symbol. The difference between the USB 3.0/3.1 Gen 1 and the USB 3.1 Gen 2 symbols are shown by the '10' hovering above the Gen 2 symbol.

If you want to distinguish between USB 1.0, 2.0 and 3.0 though, you should look at the colour of the inside of the USB port. The inside of the USB 1.0 port is a plastic white, USB 2.0 is black, and USB 3.0 is blue.

Comment: https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206513305-How-do-I-tell-if-my-Windows-PC-has-a-USB-3-0-port- "First, check the physical ports on your computer - USB 3.0 ports are sometimes (but not always) blue in color so if any of your USB ports are blue then your computer is equipped with USB 3.0. You can also check the logo above the port for the USB 3.0 SuperSpeed logo " <- note that once i've used USB 3 has been blue as you say. But apparently that isn't always the case? or perhaps wasn't always the case?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-the-blue-and-black-USB-ports "Black is typically USB 2.0 (High Speed) , but can be as low as USB 1.0"

Comment: Good point - not all manufacturers label their USB ports or give them a distinguishable sign.

Comment: You can use Device Manager if this is the case.

Comment: Though my USB ports on all my computers are coloured/labelled, so I'm used to looking at the port.

Comment: Device manager won't really tell you which usb port is where though would it?

Comment: No, but it will give you an idea of what ports you do have, and anyway, having unlabelled ports is rare, so... maybe you're just unlucky if you do have unlabelled ports? @barlop

Comment: colors are not a good indication. not every manufacturer sticks to blue being 3.0, and there's also yellow used when the usb port is high-power, but even that is not always used. I've also seen grey being used for usb 3.0, where it had the SS indicator.

Comment: I don't believe the color of the port is even part of the USB standard.

Comment: Per specifications, USB 3.x, blue is RECOMMENDED color for plastics. Not mandatory, that's why wild differences in color exist.